# C# NHibernate - Accessing an element's list throws error (failed to lazily initialize...)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, lazy-initialization

I'm using MVC2, NHibernate 3.2.

My Classes:

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{

    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.Configure();
                configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(EstoqueEquipamento).Assembly);
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

I query the element with this:

```
 public Car GetCar(object pk)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {

                return session.Get<Car>(pk);
            }
        }
```

The  Car mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateClasses" namespace="NHibernateClasses.Entities">
    <class name="Car" table="STACK.CAR" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" >
        <id name="CarId" column="CAR_ID" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SQ_CAR</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <bag name="TireList" inverse="true" generic="true" lazy="true" >
            <key>
                <column name="CarId"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Tire" />
        </bag>




        <property name="Plate" type="String" column="MAH_PLATE" />



    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Tire mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateClasses" namespace="NHibernateClasses.Entities">
    <class name="Tire" table="STACK.Tire" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" >
        <id name="TireId" column="Tire_ID" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">SQ_Tire</param>
            </generator>
        </id>


        <property name="Brand" type="String" column="MAH_BRAND" />



    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then i query the element:

```
var car = GetCar(1);//works just fine
var tirelist = car.Tires;//throws error!
```

The first line works with no problems, but the last line throws the following error:

> Initializing[Car]-failed
>   to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   Car.TireList,
>   no session or session was closed

Let me know if you need the config file also.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In GetCar you close the session (due to the `using`), before you access the Tires-collection later on in your code. Collections are loaded lazily by default in nHibernate, so make sure you fetch the collection before ending the transaction.
You could use Eager loading to make sure nHibernate loads the child collection as well.

Comment: You mean, in the GeCar method i have to call car.TireList? If i make it non-lazy will it work as is?

Comment: Those are also valid methods for making sure nHibernate loads the collection before the session is closed.

Comment: I'm using a generic repository to get the elements. What i mean is the same Get is used for a dozen entities, so i can't call the list property. Also, the Eager thing seems to fall in the same problem.

Comment: You could try modifying the mapping to specify that the collection should be loaded eagerly.

Comment: I tried set lazy to false on all mappings, and the application is incredibly slow now, to tell the truth i haven't been able to make a single query so far, it just loads infinitely.

Comment: I don't know how many collections you have, but this is a side-effect of what you did. What you most likely want to do, is put the session-handling in an actionfilter such that opening and closing a session is tied to a request. In that way you can keep your collections lazy and access a child collection in the controller. If you want to send it to a view, you're probably better of using projections and a DTO.